# js setAttribute with Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, aframe

I have a problem with setAttribute. I set an Array as the value of rotation, but it doesn't work.  Alert of `gradRoll` is a `number`. But the type of `gradRoll` is `undefined`. Why? Can anybody help me? thanks in advance.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('clockhand_roll',{
    schema:{
      type:'string', default: "secondClockhand"
    },

    init:function(){
      var data = this.data;
      var el=this.el;

      var oTime= new Date();
      var curTime;

      var clockhandPositonArray;

      if(data == "secondClockhand" ){
        curTime = oTime.getSeconds();
      }else if(data == "minuteClockhand"){
        curTime = oTime.getMinutes();
      }else if(data == "hourClockhand"){
        curTime = oTome.getHours;
      }else {
        alert("invalid input!");
      }

      //alert(curTime);  
      //clockhandPositonArray=getClockhandPosition(curTime, data);
      //alert(el.getAttribute("rotation"));

      //el.setAttribute("rotation", 'clockhandPositonArray');

      setClockhandPosition(el, curTime, data);

    }
  });

  function setClockhandPosition(el, curTime, typeOfClockhand){
    var gradForOneUnit;
    var gradRoll;
    var rotationArray;

    if(typeOfClockhand == "secondClockhand" || typeOfClockhand == "minuteClockhand"){
      gradForOneUnit=360/60;
    }else if(typeOfClockhand == "hourClockhand"){
      gradForOneUnit=360/12;
    }

    gardRoll=curTime*gradForOneUnit;

    //alert(gardRoll); //number: 354!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! why??????
    //alert(typeof(gradRoll)); //undefined!!!!!!!!!!!!!  why??????

    rotationArray=[curTime*gradForOneUnit, 0, 0];

    //alert(typeof(rotationArray));//object
    //alert(typeof(el.getAttribute("rotation"))); //object

    //alert(rotationArray); //number: 162 , 0, 0

    el.setAttribute("rotation", rotationArray); //dosn't work.
  }
```

Comment: Look for typos `gradRoll/gardRoll`

Comment: rotationArray={x: curTime * gradForOneUnit, y: 0, z: 0}; it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of people suggesting:
 `el.setAttribute("rotation", 'x'+'y' + 'z');`
 method, as far as i know, it's a bit more efficient to omit the parsing ( `'x y z' to {x,y,z}` ) and use the object in the first place :
`el.setAttribute("rotation", {x:gradRoll,y:0,z:0});`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
el.setAttribute("transform", "rotate3d,x,y,z,angle)");
```

or combine `rotateX`, `rotateY`, `rotateZ`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. rotation should be a object.

Answer (score 0):

gradRoll is undefined because the variable name is gardRoll, a typo that you repeated in the first alert but not in the second one.

It seems like you only wish to edit the X value of the rotation so try this:

```
el.setAttribute("rotation", gardRoll + ' 0 ' + '0');
```

Note that I used the variable with the typo in it.

It's a bit dirty I know but it worked for me when I had a similar issue with the position component.